# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for my Comparator Interface in Java

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I am learning about Comparator interface to solve a fractional knapsack problem.  The two arrays in line a and b indicate 3 value-weight pairs - (60, 20), (100, 50), (120, 30).  The Comparator is supposed to sort arr[] based on the ratios of v[i]/w[i].  However, The following code gives me weird error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

My Comparator seems to be trying to access index=3 of arr[], but I can't limit its access of indices.  Any solutions?

Here is my code:

```
int[] v = {60, 100, 120};  // v: values. line a
int[] w = {20, 50, 30};   // w: weights. line b
int len = v.length;
Integer[] arr = new Integer[len];

for (int i=0; i<len; i++) 
  arr[i] = v[i] / w[i];

//sort arr[] based on the ratios of v[i]/w[i]
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() {
  @Override public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
      return Double.compare(v[o1]/w[o1], v[o2]/w[o2]);
  }
});

double[] v_sorted = new double[len];
double[] w_sorted = new double[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
  v_sorted[i] = v[arr[i]];
  w_sorted[i] = w[arr[i]];
}
```

Comment: Where is array `v` or where is the variable `v` in the code?I think you mean `values` instead of `v` and `weights` instead of `w`.It would be great if you had them correctly there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to sort indexes, as represented by `o1` and `o2` in your comparator code, but your `arr` contains pre-computed ratios.

Filling the array with numbers `0` through `len-1`, inclusive, will solve the problem:

```
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) 
    arr[i] = i;
```

Now the comparator will get a pair of indexes, and compare ratios of `v[...]` to `w[...]` based on them.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you want doubles but you are creating `Integer` array.Also some others logical errors exist.Have a look at the below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Initialize arrays `values`,`weights`,arr
        int[] values = { 60, 100, 120 };
        int[] weights = { 20, 50, 30 };
        int valuesArrayLength = values.length;

        Double[] array = new Double[valuesArrayLength];

        // For loop
        for (int i = 0; i < valuesArrayLength; i++)
            array[i] = (double) (values[i] / weights[i]);

        //Pre Java8 way(@Deprecated)
        // Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Double>() {
        //     @Override
        //      public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
        //        return Double.compare(o1,o2);
        //     }
        // });
        // Sort array using a Comparator (lambda expression)
        Arrays.sort(array, (o1, o2) -> Double.compare( o1,o2));
        //The above can be even reduced to (method reference)
        //Arrays.sort(array, Double::compare);

        // Finally
        int[] valuesSorted = Arrays.stream(values).sorted().toArray();
        int[] weightsSorted = Arrays.stream(weights).sorted().toArray();

        // Testing the arrays
        System.out.println("array sorted:" + Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println("valuesSorted:" + Arrays.toString(valuesSorted));
        System.out.println("weightsSorted:" + Arrays.toString(weightsSorted));
    }
}
```